# Docker-compose cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, docker, npm

I've been trying to rewrite some of my docker-compose.yml file to change from mongodb to mysql but everytime I install a new dependency it says that it's unable to find it...

```
Cannot find module 'sequelize'
```

I've tried docker-compose build but it wont work. I'm fairly sure it's got to do with my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "3001:3000"
    environment:
     - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/test
    links:
     - database
    depends_on:
     - database
    volumes:
     - .:/starter
     - /starter/node_modules

  database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "ticketgo"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"

  adminer:
    image: "adminer"
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
     - "database"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this commands:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build
```